# What is the effect of stator magnetic flux on the rotor of Synchronous motor?

Tags: motor, induction-motor, synchronous, synchronous-motor

I get that the stator is fed 3 phase supply and the rotor is fed a dc supply. And it reaches a stage where the constant flux by dc current in rotor and the rotating magnetic flux by ac current in the stator winding locks up in N-S and S-N form and thus the rotor rotates. **BUT in asynchronous motor the rotating magnetic field induces an EMF in the rotor winding** which causes a current flow in the rotor thus generating its own magnetic flux according to Lenz's law. And because of the slip the rotor spins.
Now what happens in case of a synchronous motor? How will the rotor deal with the induced EMF created in the rotor by the rotating magnetic field of the stator?

Comment: In a synchronous motor there is no relative motion between the rotor and the stator field so there is no induced voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of the stator (armature) magnetic flux on the rotor field is called armature reaction. In synchronous machines, the effect is modeled as a slight increase in the synchronous reactance.